# ErrorException Undefined variable $siswa

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a new comer in programmer.
When i want to run my application there is an error exception undefined variable.

this is the code used in the **web.php** file:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('siswa');
});



Route::get('/siswa', 'SiswaController@index');
Route::get('/siswa/export_excel', 'SiswaController@export_excel');
Route::post('/siswa/import_excel', 'SiswaController@import_excel');
```

I think my problem on my blade (view).
I show a few of my blade because couldn't attach many code in here :

```html
        <table class='table table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>NIS</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php $i=1 @endphp
                @foreach($siswa as $s)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->nama}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->nis}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->alamat}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

this is my part of controller, I want post but there is limitation when i want post it couldn't because it will be said "many code"

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Siswa;

use Session;

use App\Exports\SiswaExport;
use App\Imports\SiswaImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiswaController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
    {
        $siswa = Siswa::all();
        return view('siswa',['siswa'=>$siswa]);
    }

    public function export_excel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new SiswaExport, 'siswa.xlsx');
    }

    public function import_excel(Request $request) 
    {
        // validasi
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
        ]);

        // menangkap file excel
        $file = $request->file('file');

        // membuat nama file unik
        $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // upload ke folder file_siswa di dalam folder public
        $file->move('file_siswa',$nama_file);

        // import data
        Excel::import(new SiswaImport, public_path('/file_siswa/'.$nama_file));

        // notifikasi dengan session
        Session::flash('sukses','Data Siswa Berhasil Diimport!');

        // alihkan halaman kembali
        return redirect('/siswa');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which route you are visiting that causes error??

Comment: I'm confused whether route, blade (view) or controller.
Because i when i post my blade or controller it couldn't

Comment: Try to put the code of blade file or controller file , so we can understand what causes error !

Comment: can you add your controller or the function that you use to return this view

Comment: Post the code where you use return statment for opening this blade file

Comment: this man is not posting proper code how anyone can help him

Comment: put controller code here

Comment: We can't help you if you don't put everything you need !

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm apologize. it's not that I don't want to but the limitations of the post.
Please need help for my case
@RushikeshGanesh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [where is an ErrorException Undefined variable $siswa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112434/where-is-an-errorexception-undefined-variable-siswa)

Answer (score 0):

You must return view with $siswa variable in order to access to it through blade template.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views

Answer (score 0):

Define home route, and from your index method in siswaController pass the parameter in your view which is 'siswa'.

**In web.php:**

`Route::get('/','SiswaController@index');`

**In SiswaController.php:**

```
public function index(){
 $siswa = ['name'=>'John',age=>23, email=>'joba@shija.com'];
 return view('siswa',['siswa'=>'$siswa']);}
```

Comment: I was posted my controller