# where is an ErrorException Undefined variable $siswa

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, undefined

I was posting on last discussion, may be is no clear my problem.
I'm apologize if I was created 2 same discussion
And now I will attach all information including all code, I hope it can be fixed soon.

and there are **SiswaController.php**, I hope can help all of you for support my problem.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Siswa;

use Session;


use App\Exports\SiswaExport;
use App\Imports\SiswaImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiswaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $siswa = Siswa::all();
        return view('siswa',['siswa'=>$siswa]);
    }

    public function export_excel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new SiswaExport, 'siswa.xlsx');
    }

    public function import_excel(Request $request) 
    {
        // validasi
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
        ]);

        // menangkap file excel
        $file = $request->file('file');

        // membuat nama file unik
        $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // upload ke folder file_siswa di dalam folder public
        $file->move('file_siswa',$nama_file);

        // import data
        Excel::import(new SiswaImport, public_path('/file_siswa/'.$nama_file));

        // notifikasi dengan session
        Session::flash('sukses','Data Siswa Berhasil Diimport!');

        // alihkan halaman kembali
        return redirect('/siswa');
    }
}
```

There is **siswa.blade.php**

```
        <a href="/siswa/export_excel" class="btn btn-success my-3" target="_blank">EXPORT EXCEL</a>

        <table class='table table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>NIS</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php $i=1 @endphp
                @foreach($siswa as $s)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->nama}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->nis}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->alamat}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

There are **web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'SiswaController@index');
Route::get('/siswa', 'SiswaController@index');
Route::get('/siswa/export_excel', 'SiswaController@export_excel');
Route::post('/siswa/import_excel', 'SiswaController@import_excel');
```

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh that is basically the same thing, not everyone likes to use `compact()`

Comment: @GertB. could you help me?

Comment: I was follow from this website https://www.malasngoding.com/import-excel-laravel/, but there is problem when trying

Comment: On what action do you get the error, the index function looks fine.

Comment: I don't know, there is error 
> ErrorException
Undefined variable $siswa (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\report_sales\resources\views\siswa.blade.php)

Comment: And what is the URL? you should change the route for `/` to `Route::get('/', 'SiswaController@index');`and clear the route cache

Comment: this is my URL : http://localhost:8080/report_sales/public/)

Comment: Your routing is never gonna work good that way. You need to create a virtual host that points to the laravel public folder. Or even better: use `php artisan serve` instead of running it with XAMPP. XAMPP might not be the best local environment to run Laravel, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @GertB. I was tried using php artisan serve with command prompt, but same error. What could I do for you can see my screen? for help me better

Comment: Did you change the home route as i commented? That is your problem. you load the view without running the controller. You can't share your screen, thats just not how SO works

Comment: I update my question and my route as your comment but have error when doing clear config

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of your new Route line. also remove the first Route definition for `/` that returns the view. `config:cache` does not remove your route cache, use `route:cache`

Comment: there is error `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD`

Comment: On the domain of the artisan serve? Or are you still using the XAMPP URL

Comment: I think is yes on artisan serve, how could check on domain artisan serve or no? <br/>yes still using XAMPP URL, on my local pc

Comment: is the url you use still localhost:8080/report_sales/public ? because that wil not work. The artisan serve returns a url localhost with a port, use that URL and the route should work

Comment: yes, still use localhost:8080/report_sales/public , so these mean using  `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and with `php artisan serve`  on command prompt?

Comment: Hi there is any information or command can I do?

Comment: if http://127.0.0.1:8000 is the domain that php artisan serve returns, yes, use that one

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to include **Siswa** model in your **SiswaController.php**.

Add that model path and try.

```
use App\Models\Siswa;
```

I am sure error will be solved.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GertB.  That's ok , but it's solution.

Comment: I was tried, it still same error "ErrorException
Undefined variable $siswa (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\report_sales\resources\views\siswa.blade.php)
http://localhost:8080/report_sales/public/"

Comment: If the use statement is missing you get a other error. It is needed in his code, but not causing the error

Comment: @GertB. I will give the code how to write it?

Comment: @LucasFutami the first question is: what is the route that is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your route file web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('siswa');
});
```

here $siswa is not passed, so it is resulting undefined variable $siswa.

I think you want to direct it into `SiswaController@index`

Comment: I'm trying like this 
``` Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('SiswaController@index');
});


Route::get('/siswa', 'SiswaController@index');
Route::get('/siswa/export_excel', 'SiswaController@export_excel');
Route::post('/siswa/import_excel', 'SiswaController@import_excel');
```
But there is error message "InvalidArgumentException
View [SiswaController@index] not found."

Comment: `Route::get('', 'SiswaController@index' );` should be enough.

Comment: I'm trying and have an error "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [SiswaController] does not exist."

Comment: @LucasFutami so your namespace is incorrect, tell me the namespace of your controller. your route file is not able to recognize it now.

Comment: @LucasFutami you can also import your controller before using it. just use import something like `use App\Http\Controllers\SiswaController;` at top of your web.php .

Comment: I've added in my controller, but still same error

Comment: @LucasFutami can you update your question with your changes?

Comment: @LucasFutami yes, so that I can understand what exactly you have done now.

Comment: I update my question on above please see it

Comment: @LucasFutami sorry, I was away for lunch, will check in a minute.

Comment: @LucasFutami in your `web.php` add `use App\Http\Controllers\SiswaController;`  after `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` .